# How should the data be sent for datatype TIME in Sequelize/ Node JS

Tags: node.js, sql-server, sequelize.js

I have a time column in my mssql db. I want to post data through an API to this table, but this field throws the error - "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string". I am sending the time field as a string like "13:00". When getting the data from db through sequelize, I get as an ISOString like "1970-01-01T08:00:00.000Z", but the data on the db is like "13:00:00"(hh:mm:ss). I tried sending "13:00:00" and "1970-01-01T08:00:00.000Z", both do not seem to work.

Comment: can you post your table structure and your model definition?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I created a simple nodejs app with sequelize and was able to insert both `13:00` and `13:00:00` for `Time` Datatype successfully.

I have checked with both `Time` and `Date` datatypes.
I got this error `Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string` only when I tried to insert `13:00` into `Date` datatype. So check the datatype of your column and make sure it is `Time` and not `Date`

Kindly refer this code and check where you have gone wrong.

```
var http = require('http');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = new Sequelize('DBName', 'UserName', 'Password', {
  host: 'localhost',  
  port:12672,
  dialect: 'mssql',
  options:{
    encrypt:false,
    instancename: 'SQLEXPRESS'
  }
});



const User2 = sequelize.define('user2', {
  name: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING
  },
  DateTimeCol: {
    type: Sequelize.DATE
  },
  TimeCol: {
    type: Sequelize.TIME
  }
});

User2.sync().then(() => {
   User2.create({
    name: 'Rahul',
    DateTimeCol: '2018-01-01T08:00:00.000Z',
    TimeCol: '13:00'
  });
  User2.findAll().then(data => console.log(data));
});


var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
res.writeHead(200);
res.end();
});
server.listen(8080);
```

Comment: You can send as a string, what happened was I tried to insert '24:00' which will fail.

Comment: That is because 24:00 is actually 00:00

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/functions-formatting.html Table 9-22. Template Patterns for Date/Time Formatting